# How to listen for divider move in SashForm in SWT?

Tags: java, swt, scrolledcomposite

How to listen for divider move in `SashForm` in `SWT`?

I want to resize content object so that it was the width of the `ScrolledComposite` (in one of the parts of `SashForm`) and automatic height.

Comment: What do you mean by "divider"?

Comment: Oh :) Wrote something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific event for the `SashForm` movement. You could add a resize listener to the parts added to the `SashForm`.

```
control.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener()
 {
   @Override
   public void handleEvent(final Event event)
   {
     // TODO handle reize
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

so I had to find this out on myself, because it is not mentioned in the documentation:

```
sashForm.getChildren();
```

will give you back the children **and** the Sashes **but** only after you called

```
sashForm.getParent.layout();
```

And only if there is a Sash (if you have added 2 children minimum)

Then you got the Sash and you can register any Listener you want ;)
Hopefully there will be an interface for that in the future.(a public one)